# How to control a separate WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, api-design

I'm developing a Revit add-on which performs some lengthy tasks. During the process, I want to display a simple WPF window with an indeterminate progress bar, a label to inform about current process and a button to enable aborting.
I already tried the most obvious ways of accomplishing that: creating a WPF window inside the add-on and displaying it, but the problem is that the UI gets frozen, no matter how I implement this. During some processes, the whole Revit UI gets frozen/white so I really wouldn't expect my embedded WPF window would behave normally in these conditions anyway.

The workaround I figured out was to have the WPF window as a separate app (EXE file) I could run from the add-on. I based my implementation on [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224031/Passing-Parameters-to-a-Running-Application-in-WPF) .
The good part of it is that it doesn't hang no matter what is happening with Revit.
The bad part is that the sequence of how Windows is queuing the calls of my separate WPF app is sometimes different from the sequence of these calls from my add-on. It sometimes results in a situation when the Revit process is over but the WPF window is still displayed (waiting for the final, closing call which had been apparently already executed, but then the app got reactivated with another, delayed call).

Preferably I would like to handle the WPF app the same way as you can i.e. handle an Excel application from .NET. You create an ExcelApp object, do what you want with it and dispose of in the end.
The problem is I don't have a clue of how to do this.

- How should I expose the WPF app's API to my add-on?
- Could it be possible to have the WPF app responsive and controlled from the Revit add-on at the same time? (user can still click the abort button, the indeterminate progress bar doesn't freeze)

Comment: The second part turns this into an x-y-question, really. I'd go back to your first approach and figrue out how to do lengthy tasks asynchronously.

Comment: @Fildor In Revit API you can't do it asynchronously. This is why I have the workaround, i just want to improve it.

Comment: Do you have some link to Revit Docs? Unfortunately I am totally unfamiliar with it. I just thought it should be possible if it allows for WPF add-ons.

Comment: @Fildor [this](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/asynchronous-api-calls-and-idling.html) and [this](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/no-multithreading-in-revit.html) explain the problem with multighreading and async methods in Revit API. But I just found found [this](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/creating-an-addin-that-shows-process-asynchronously/m-p/8306407) - I need to explore it and see if it helps. Still I expect that if Revit UI gets frozen, as it sometimes does, the WPF window will too, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The First thing to know is about interacting between two processes. there are some Standard approaches:

- Interacting through Socket (Socket Programming)
- Using Named PipeLines (Useful when your messages aren't so long)

There are some other predefined Libraries based on above techniques. Using a FileSystem Based method is not a reliable way to proof the outputs.

This was a part of your solution. The next step is to use **Threading** in your WPF application. I'm not familiar to Revit and I don't know how it works. 
UI freezing is normal in a long running process. because UI is busy and it can't answer your requests (e.g Mouse Move, Click, ...). So using a **Thread** you can put your long running process into a separate place and wait for the response at the end of it.

There is a problem while using a Thread. Because you left your UI and started your long running process on a separate Thread, you can't directly access to your ProgressBar. In this situations you have to use **ThreadDispacher**. It's not a terrifying concept, it just a three line of codes that will adds to your callings. 
for example:

```
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            ProgressBar.Value++;
        });
```

Search for a Library to doing your IPC (Inter Process Communication) to get the result faster (or you can learn about above techniques to do it by your means) and next add a simple thread to your WPF application so you be able to Start, Pause and resume the running job based on the situation.

Comment: To add to your list of possible approaches: [Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Also, especially in WPF, instead of using a Thread, I'd recommend using async/await and Task bundled with [IProgress/Progress](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html).

Comment: The problem with Revit API is that it doesn't support multithreading. Async/Await are not supported as well. This is why I mentioned that the obvious ways of tackling the problem failed.

Comment: @adam.k But if you have it in a separate exe, you can use async there, don't you?

Comment: @Fildor yes, inside the WPF app I can. But my current workaround has no issues of frozen UI, just the call queue is sometimes wrong.